# Windows authentication not loading user

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have configured my Business Application to use Windows Authentication. From everything that I have read I don't need to change anything, and it should just load the currently logged in user.  This is not the case.  In the `Application_Loaded` method, the `User` is empty.

[image: Empty User]

Even when I upload the project to a server, I still get an empty user.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you edit web.config http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28v=vs.95%29.aspx .I think it may be related with your browser security settings also. On the link reviewing "Accessing the Service from Silverlight" part might be helpfull for you. Please share when you succeed!

Comment: @DavutGürbüz - yes, followed that link but still without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at this for a whole day, I've finally found the problem.  I had to remove all of the `<roles>`, `<profile>` and `<membership>` from the `web.config`.  I also added `[ProfileUsage(IsExcluded=false)]` to the `FriendlyName` property in the `User` class.

Comment: It means it still tries auth.by asp.net membership denpending of your setting. For intranet solutions your tip will be beneficial.very well.